# Calculating GEO transformation params in Vega/d3

Tags: d3.js, vega

Copy this code to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:GraphSandbox

The scale and translate parameters of the [geo transformation](https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Data-Transforms#-geo) were manually set to match the width & height of the image (see red crosses).  How can I make it so that geo transformation matches the entire graph size (or maybe some signal values) automatically, without the manual adjustments?

**UPDATE:**  The translation parameter should have been set to HALF of WIDTH and HEIGHT of the image. See the answer below, and center should have been set to [0,0]. For equirectangular projection, the graph size should have ration 2:1.

```json
{
  "version": 2, "width": 800, "height": 400, "padding": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data",
      "values": [
        {"lat":0, "lon":0},
        {"lat":90, "lon":-180},
        {"lat":-90, "lon":180}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "image",
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "url": {"value": "wikirawupload:{{filepath:Earthmap1000x500compac.jpg|190}}"},
          "width": {"signal": "width"},
          "height": {"signal": "height"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "points",
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {
        "data": "data",
        "transform": [{
            "type": "geo",
            "projection": "equirectangular",
            "scale": 127,
            "center": [0,0],
            "translate": [400,200],
            "lon": "lon",
            "lat": "lat"
        }]
      },
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"field": "layout_x"},
          "y": {"field": "layout_y"},
          "fill": {"value": "#ff0000"},
          "size": {"value": 500},
          "shape": {"value": "cross"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer (the example above was updated):  The `"translate"` should be set to the center of the image. The `"center"` on the other hand should be set to [0,0]. The `"scale"` for the `equirectangular` projection needs to be set to `width/(2*PI)`